# INSERT query not inserting data but, performs the echo which states INSERT is successful

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code snippet:

```
$get_data = mysqli_query ($connect, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'");
    $row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($get_data);
            $age = $row2['age'];

$get_data2 = mysqli_query ($connect, "SELECT * FROM user_bio WHERE username = '$username'");
    $row3 = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($get_data2);
            $bio = $row3['about_me'];   
            $studying = $row3['studying'];
            $lang = $row3['language'];
            $rel_status = $row3['relationship_status'];

$about_me = htmlentities(trim(strip_tags(@$_POST['biotextarea'])));
        $new_studying = htmlentities(trim(strip_tags(@$_POST['studying'])));
        $new_lang = htmlentities(trim(strip_tags(@$_POST['lang'])));
        $new_rel = htmlentities(strip_tags(@$_POST['rel']));

        if(isset($_POST['update_data'])){
            // need to check if the username has data already in the db, if so, then we update the data, otherwise we insert data.
                $get_bio = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM user_bio WHERE username ='$username'");
                $row_returned = mysqli_num_rows($get_bio);

                if ($row_returned == 0){
                    $insert_query = mysqli_query ($connect, "INSERT INTO user_bio (id, age, studying, language, relationship_status, username, about_me) 
                                                    VALUES ('', '$age','$new_studying','$new_lang','$new_rel', '$username', '$about_me'");                                                          
                        echo "  <div class='details_updated'>
                                    <p> Details added successfully! </p>
                                </div>";
                } else {    
                    $update_details_query = mysqli_query ($connect, "UPDATE user_bio SET studying ='$new_studying', language ='$new_lang', 
                                                                relationship_status = '$new_rel', about_me = '$about_me' WHERE username ='$username'");
                        echo "  <div class='details_updated'>
                                    <p> Details updated successfully! </p>
                                </div>";
                }
            }
```

The idea is that when a user uploads their `bio`, the query with either `INSERT` or `UPDATE` based on if a row already exists for that `username`. For example, I have one row manually inserted for username `Conor`:

```
id: 1
age: 30
studying: Business
language: English
relationship_status: Single
username: conor
about_me: This is conor's bio.
```

If I log in as Conor, and go to `account_settings_bio.php`, where conor can edit their bio, the `UPDATE` query (else statement) would run because there is a row in the db for username `conor`. However, if I log in as `Alice` and go to `account_settings_bio.php`, the INSERT query should run because no data for alice exists in the `user_bio` table.

Now, the issue is that, when I am logged in as Alice, and I go to `account_settings_bio.php`, I add all my details and click submit, it echo's the message which should occur when the `INSERT` query is successful i.e.                                    `<p> Details added successfully! </p>` - but no new row is added in the database?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing the setting that causes mysqli to throw an exception when an SQL error happens.

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

If that's not set, then mysqli doesn't throw an error, and the code has to do the check to see if the SQL statement was successful.

After this:

```
  $insert_query = mysqli_query ($connect, "INSERT INTO
```

You'd need to check if `$insert_query` evaluates to TRUE to know if the statement execution was successful.

Otherwise, the code is putting it's pinky finger to the corner of its mouth, Dr.Evil-style, and saying "I just assume it all went to plan. What?"